# pass two different output in a function

Tags: python, function

I  am not sure if it possible to pass the output of two different functions in another function. Ie output of def A() and def B() are to be passed in to def C().

to make it easy to understand, I chose the following problem as an example.

Problem: I want to **Add** the **product** and **division** of two numbers. For that I made three function

```
def product(a,b):
  M=a*b

def division(a,b):
  D=a/b
```

Now I want to add **M** and **D** and the result will be **(a*b)+(a/b)**.

for this I made another function named **add** to get the sum

```
def add(M,D):
  X=M+D
  print(X)
```

But didn't find any way to pass **M** and **D** in the **add** .

Comment: Why not call your `product` and `division` functions from inside `add` ?

For example, inside `add`, just have `print(product(M,D)+division(M,D))`

(Make sure to `return` your values at the end of the product and division functions!)

Comment: Yes, functions can use other functions as parameters and functions can return values.

Comment: @CharlesDupont for this example Yes!, but the real problem is bit complex where I have to have two different functions for initial calculation, and third function for the final calculation.

Comment: Might I recommend you first go over the basics of python and programming in general. You dont return said values, they are local variables meaning they get lost once the functions finish, And there is no indicator they are global. Spend some time learning the basics instead of asking here.

Comment: If you are not aware that functions can `return` things, it is probably a good idea to do a [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) instead of piecing together the absolute basics via questions.

Comment: @Sayse Thanks. Sorry, I am new to coding. Definitely I will go through the python module

Comment: You should ask it as a new question, you've invalidated the answers given to you.

Comment: @Sayse Thanks I 'll ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Sayse Please find it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850888/finding-cdrs-in-ngs-data  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to `return` a result from your functions, and then call them in the definition of `add`

```py
def product(a,b):
  M=a*b
  return M

def division(a,b):
  D=a/b
  return D

def add(a,b):
  return product(a,b) + division(a,b)
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact there is no check whether b is zero, this is ok :)

Comment: @JosipJuros i have updated my problem

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you simply call the functions in add?

```
def add(a, b):
    return product(a,b) + division(a,b)
```

Comment: Since op's function didn't contain some `return` the code you wrote won't work. But it's indeed the way to work around

Answer (score -2):

```js
def product(a,b):
  return a*b

def division(a,b):
  return a/b
def add(m, n):
  return m+n

add(product(10,2), division(10,2))
```